# How to access context data with useContext in the root/Parent entry?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-vaughan-65x33).

I can successfully get and set context data through the children components. but why I can't access them in the parent?

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const context = useContext(MyContext)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyContextProvider>
        <Comp1 />
        <Comp2 />
        <p>
          Result inside: {context.selection}
        </p>
      </MyContextProvider>
      <p>
        Result outside: {context.selection}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the children component.

```
const Comp1 = () => {
    const context = useContext(MyContext)
    return (
        <div>
            <p>current: {context.selection}</p>
            <button onClick={() => context.setSelection && context.setSelection(123)}>Set to '123'</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and here's the context file.

```
interface MyContextProviderType {
    children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
}

interface ContextProps {
    selection: string
    setSelection: Function
}

export const MyContext = createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({})

export const MyContextProvider = ({children}: MyContextProviderType) => {
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState('')
    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{selection, setSelection}}>
            {children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Appreciate for the help!

Comment: You can't; to consume a context you must be inside a provider.

Comment: That’s why I have inside and outside trys.

Comment: do you have a use case where you can't wrap both inside and outside in the `<MyContextProvider>`?

Answer (score 0):

The component that calls

```
useContext(MyContext)
```

has to have a matching provider higher in the tree.
otherwise, the value will be whatever you initialized the context with.
In this case this empty object:

```
createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({})
```

You could render your App component inside the provider to make your sandbox work

```
<MyContextProvider><App /></MyContextProvider>
```